# Android request permission doesn't work for notifications permissions

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, android-service-binding

Why this code works:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            666);

## In the manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

and this code doesn't work:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE},
            666);

## In the manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
```

The first snippet starts the request permission activity asking for read contacts permissions.
The last snippet doesn't show the activity and in the logs there is this message:

```
10-16 12:19:48.061 1138-3635/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS pkg=com.google.android.packageinstaller cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity (has extras)} from uid 10147 on display 0
```

So, what I'm supposed to do to ask notifications permissions?
Target API is v24 and the minimum sdk version is 23.

Comment: "So, what I'm supposed to do to ask notifications permissions?" -- you don't. First, you get rid of that Java code. Then, you get rid of that `<uses-permission>` element. `BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` is a system permission, one that your app cannot hold.

Answer (score 3):

well, run time permissions are asked only for dangerous permissions, since notification service is not a dangerous permission you need not ask it. here is the list of all dangerous and not dangerous permissions.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

p.s. no matter permission is dangerous or normal, both must be declared in manifest, only difference is in run time requests.

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE)

```
BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE

String BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE

Must be required by an NotificationListenerService, to ensure that only the system can bind to it.
```

Which means it doesn't necessarily need to grant by user at runtime. Rather, it needs to be declared in manifest.xml under a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html).
Something like this,

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
          android:label="@string/service_name"
          android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the list of permissions you have to ask
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

> READ_CALENDAR, WRITE_CALENDAR
>
> CAMERA
>
> READ_CONTACTS, WRITE_CONTACTS, GET_ACCOUNTS
>
> ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,      RECORD_AUDIO
>
> READ_PHONE_STATE, CALL_PHONE, READ_CALL_LOG, WRITE_CALL_LOG, ADD_VOICEMAIL
>   USE_SIP, PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
>
> BODY_SENSORS
>
> SEND_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, READ_SMS, RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, RECEIVE_MMS
>
> READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE